# SIGABRT (signal SIGABRT) while running malloc

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, malloc

The problem in the program occurs when malloc is run several times. I am getting the error: `SIGABRT (signal SIGABRT)`. I've had a look at similar questions, but nothing has helped so far.

The program is straightforward, so if you like you could just skip to the program below. I have also given an explanation, incase you might need it.

please let me know if you have any questions, and I'll be sure to answer them.

**The program explained:**

In main I have a pointer array (line) where each pointer points to a string that represents a line.  I am then calling a function to get lines from an input.

The getlines function has two for loops, one inside the other.

1. The outside loop moves to the next pointer in the pointer array. Since each pointer represents a line, it moves to the next line, at the end of the inside loop.
2. The inside loop adds characters till end of file, or new line is reached. It also checks that the string does not exceed the MAXLINE.

   1. At the start of the inside loop, malloc is used to add a pointer inside the array, which would reference to the string (the line).
   2. Characters are then added from the input, and linked to this pointer.

**Below is the program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXLINES 100
#define MAXLINE 100

int main() {
    char *line[MAXLINES];
    getlines(line);
}

void getlines(char **line){
    int c = 0;
    char *l = 0;
    for(;c!= EOF; line++) {
        for (*line = NULL; (l - *line) != MAXLINE && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; l++) {
            if (*line == NULL) {
                *line = malloc(sizeof(char));
                l = *line;
            }
            *l = c;
        }
        *l = '\0';
    }
    *line = NULL;
}
```

Thank you again :)

Comment: to avoid confusion, I added Maxline, and Maxlines to distinguish them

Comment: the includes are missing...

Comment: @SobhanMohammadpour I did have them, forgot to add them above, just added them.

Comment: Your code can perform the following sequence: `*line = malloc(sizeof(char)); l = *line; l++; *l = c;`. This assigns to `*l` when `l` points beyond the allocated block. Is the problem simply a missing `* MAXLINE` in the `malloc`? /// There are other problems. `(l - *line) != MAXLINE` is wrong. You want to compare current `line` against original `line`.

Comment: @ikegami Actually, l++ gets incremented after *l = c; . Please have a look at the brackets, and thank you for your help. The error happens with malloc.  `(l - *line) != MAXLINE` is just calculating the total distance. *line points to the starting position, whereas l would point to a new position after incrementing

Comment: Re "*Actually, l++ gets incremented after `*l = c;`*", It's a loop, you do `*l = c;` both before and after `l++`.

Comment: I'm having a look, thank you :)

Comment: Ignore what I said after `///`. I was confusing `MAXLINE` and `MAXLINES`. You are missing a check for `MAXLINES`, though.

Comment: @ikegami yes so after incrementing, the next address of l would get the next character. So I'm trying to make a string. Sorry, I'm a a bit confused

Comment: Yes, but because you only allocated *one* character instead of `MAXLINE` of them, there is no next character.

Comment: @ikegami I know, but I'm testing with 5 lines right now, so should be fine. I'll add that later. It's just that if I run the code, half the time it runs fine. But half the time it doesn't, and I get the malloc error

Comment: Yes, and I explained why

Comment: The code just stops at malloc, and that's when I get the error. Everything works smoothly. If you have a chance, and would run it through a debugger, I would really appreciate it

Comment: @ikegami let me double check again

Comment: @ikegami aah I see. This was very help `because you only allocated one character instead of MAXLINE of them, there is no next character. ` Thank you, I didn't know this :)